# Qt custom look and feel?

Tags: c++, qt, look-and-feel

can I force my Qt application to use different look and feel just like it is done in KDE ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always change styles of widgets using QApplication::setStyle.
There are a few predefined options available in Qt4.

In main.cpp do something like this

```
#include <QPlastiqueStyle>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
[...]

    QApplication::setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle());
}
```

This way your application will alwyas look the same on different OS.
In my opinion Plastique looks better under windowsXP/2000 then default QWindowsXPStyle.
Cleanlooks is quite nice too.

There are other options:

```
#include <QPlastiqueStyle>
#include <QCleanlooksStyle>
#include <QWindowsXPStyle>
#include <QWindowsVistaStyle>
#include <QMotifStyle>
#include <QCDEStyle>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS to style widgets https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html