# Is there a way to implement consistent look and feel of a Qt5 application across different OS and Linux distribution

Tags: qt, qt5, cross-platform

I have a Qt5 application that is available for Linux and Windows (eventually MacOS in the future as well). Unfortunately, the widgets that are shipped with the application (ComboBox, SpinEdits, ToolButtons, ...) don't look the same when build on Ubuntu, OpenSuse or Windows. I would prefer the KDE Style  if possible to be used across all versions.

I came across this solution [Qt custom look and feel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358751/qt-custom-look-and-feel) but it looks like it doesn't work for Qt5 anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this without writing Styles for every widget?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Go `share/qt5/examples/widgets/widgets/styles` for an advanced usage. But basically `QApplication::setStyle("stylename");` where "stylename" is one from `QStyleFactory::keys();` does the trick. Or just add "-style fusion" to the command line of any Qt app (I believe "fusion" is platform-independent in Qt5).

Comment: I stand corrected, you can set the style like described. Fusion seems to be generally available but unfortunately one of the ugliest. Is it possible to deploy a style (oxygen or breez) with the application?

Comment: You can definitely deploy your own style (by overwriting a bunch of virtual methods like in"styles", or by providing a pack of resources like in "stylesheet" Qt example applications). However, the predefined styles (except "fusion") are not intended to be cross-platform. Maybe you could eventually make it work somehow, but generally that's a bad idea to do "hacks" while you strive for the most possible portability.

Comment: So the usual approach when deploying cross platform is to use fusion? Is it an option to use fusion for every platform but have a stylesheet that tweaks some appearances, like combobox size for example?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can use QSS. Also, if you hate "Fusion" so much, you can download source code for old "Plastique" or "Cleanlooks" styles.  It's not included in the main package anymore, but it's still available under "qtstyleplugins" subtree.